# Can the barriers to posting be shown before the human verification?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, captcha

It's quite frustrating to prove I'm a human right before being told that I'm not allowed to post for x and y reasons.. why not wait to check that I'm a human until after verifying it's ok to post?